# Choose Default Value from DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm passing in a list of statuses into an Html.DropDownList. I've been searching for a way to choose one of those items as the default, so if the user doesn't change anything, the correct status is passed back to the model. Everything I've found deals with adding an additional value (usually a "null" option) to the list.

How do I default to an already existing item?

Model:

```
public class ListStatus
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid StatusID { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<ListStatus> Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("StatusID", Model.Statuses.Select(s => new SelectListItem() { Text = s.Name, Value = s.StatusID.ToString() }), new { @class = "medium", required = true })
```

Sample Data:

```
'11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111': Option 1,
'22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222': Default,
'33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333': Option 3,
'44444444-4444-4444-4444-444444444444': Option 4
```

Comment: Your binding to the `StatusID` property of the model you pass to the view, so just set the value of `StatusID` to match one of the option values in the controller before you pass he model to the view and it will be selected - that's how model binding works. And if the view model does not contain a property `Guid StatusID` then add one (and you should use the strongly typed `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatusID, Model.Statuses)` where `Statuses` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and you generate the `SelectList` in the controller, not the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another field to your ViewModel say SelectedStatus and set its value to your desired default. Then you can use @Html.DropDownListFor to display default value.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Guid SelectedStatus {get;set;}
    public List<ListStatus> Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<ListStatus> lstStatus = new List<ListStatus>(){
        new ListStatus() { Name="X",StatusID = Guid.NewGuid() },
        new ListStatus() { Name="Y",StatusID = Guid.NewGuid() },
        new ListStatus() { Name="Z",StatusID = Guid.NewGuid() }
    };

    ViewModel objModel = new ViewModel();
    objModel.Statuses  = lstStatus;
    objModel.SelectedStatus = lstStatus[1].StatusID; // Select whatever you want here to be default.

    return View(objModel);
}
```

In your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedStatus, Model.Statuses.Select(s => new SelectListItem() { Text = s.Name, Value = s.StatusID.ToString() }), new { @class = "medium", required = true })
```

Here is fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/vTJhaj

Answer (score 0):

If you build a `List<SelectListItem>` in your controller and pass it back on the view model, you can easily find the one you want selected by default by using the `Selected` property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.118).aspx

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Statuses { get; set; }
}


// in controller
ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

// assumes listStatuses is still your ListStatus type.
model.Statuses = listStatuses.Select(s => new SelectListItem() { 
    Text = s.Name, 
    Value = s.StatusID.ToString(),

    // or whatever your criteria may be.
    Selected = s.Name == "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222"
})
```

Now you don't need to convert to new types in the view, either.